# Displaying the number of rows in footer of webix grid

Tags: javascript, datatable, grid, rows, webix

Is there an easy way to display the number of DataTable rows in its footer? I've found [the demo](http://docs.webix.com/samples/15_datatable/12_header_footer/06_counter.html) with the counter in the footer with a summColumn function, but I can't find the function for counting rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must defined a new dataFilter by extending [summColumn](http://docs.webix.com/datatable__headers_footers.html#sumcounterinthefooter) like this:

```
webix.ui.datafilter.countColumn = webix.extend({
    refresh: function (master, node, value) {
        var result = 0;
        master.mapCells(null, value.columnId, null, 1, function (value) {
            result++;
            return value;
        });

        node.firstChild.innerHTML = result;
    }
}, webix.ui.datafilter.summColumn);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try:

```
webix.ui.datafilter.countColumn = webix.extend({
refresh: function (master, node, value) {
        node.firstChild.innerHTML = master.count();
    }
}, webix.ui.datafilter.summColumn);
```

Comment: Can you explain how this helps?